# How to create UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm trying to implement UIcollectionView inside UITableViewCell. I've tried several methods but none of them works for me. Looks like tableView just doesn't know which size cell should be.

```
import UIKit

class MovieVideosTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "MovieVideosTableViewCell"
    private var collectionView: UICollectionView! = nil
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        print("Inited \(type(of: self))")
        setupCollectionView()
        addSubview(collectionView)
        setupConstraints()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

private extension MovieVideosTableViewCell {
    func setupCollectionView() {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: contentView.bounds.width/2, height: contentView.bounds.height)
        
        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: contentView.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.register(MovieDetailsCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: MovieDetailsCollectionViewCell.identifier)
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }
    
    func setupConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use `contentView.bounds` during the cell class `init` -- at which point the bounds is undetermined. You're also trying to set the `itemSize` **`.height`** to the `contentView.bounds.height`, while at the same time using constraints to set the contentView's height to the height of the collection view. Lot's of discussions and examples out there -- search for `uitableviewcell with embedded uicollectionview`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the actual problem was in constraints. I used `collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint` twice, instead of `collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint`

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but maybe the new Compositional Layout for collectionView would be useful for you.
You can create multiples sections with different configuration for each cell.

You can check it out here -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcompositionallayout